# Debug performance problems with CTE

Tags: postgresql, common-table-expression

We have a use case in our application where we first copy a csv file to a **staging** table - and then insert the validated data into a second table **participants**. The newly created participant id (primary key) is then updated in the **staging** table for further processing.

In our application we constantly run into performance problems. Sometimes this procedure works with 100 000 rows in 15-20 seconds. Sometimes it will never finish in sane time (pg_cancel_backend to the rescue).

When I tried to create a SO worthy minimal test case I was not able to reproduce the problem :/ . So this is an attempt to get some advice how to debug further or rewrite the underlying query.

- PHP App with Doctrine DBAL
- Postgres 10.5

We are doing this with a CTE - basically like this:

```
WITH inserted_participants AS (
    INSERT INTO participants (email, project_id, survey_token, participant_uname)
    SELECT
        staging.email,
        1,
        staging.generated_token,
        staging.email -- is used as uname
    FROM
        staging
    RETURNING
        participants.participant_id,
        participants.participant_uname
) -- Update existing staging data with newly created participant_id
UPDATE
    staging  AS stage_update
SET
    resulting_participant_id = inserted_participants.participant_id
FROM
    inserted_participants
WHERE stage_update.email = inserted_participants.participant_uname;
```

Again: I cannot reproduce the performance problems with this test case. I suspect that it has something to do with the CTE.

Can this be rewritten without using a CTE and still have the safety of returning the newly created rows and updating these in the staging table?

This is the table structure for the minimal test case:

```
CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS citext;

CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS "pgcrypto";

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS public.staging;

CREATE TABLE public.staging
(
    staging_id serial,
    email citext COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    generated_token character varying(255) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    resulting_participant_id integer,
    CONSTRAINT staging_pkey PRIMARY KEY (staging_id),
    CONSTRAINT unique_generated_token UNIQUE (generated_token)
);

CREATE INDEX ON public.staging (email);
CREATE INDEX ON public.staging (generated_token);

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS public.participants;

CREATE TABLE public.participants
(
    participant_id serial,
    email citext COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    project_id integer NOT NULL,
    survey_token character varying(255) COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    participant_uname citext COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT participants_pkey PRIMARY KEY (participant_id),
    CONSTRAINT participants_participant_uname_project_id_key UNIQUE (participant_uname, project_id),
    CONSTRAINT participants_project_id_email_key UNIQUE (project_id, email),
    CONSTRAINT participants_project_id_participant_uname_key UNIQUE (project_id, participant_uname),
    CONSTRAINT participants_survey_token_key UNIQUE (survey_token)
);

CREATE INDEX ON public.participants (participant_uname);
CREATE INDEX ON public.participants (project_id);
```

And the dummy data I used:

```
INSERT INTO 
    staging (staging_id, email, generated_token)
SELECT 
    generate_series(1,100000),
    gen_random_uuid()::citext,
    gen_random_uuid()::TEXT;
```

Comment: Maybe you are blocked by another session.

Comment: @LukaszSzozda I am able to reproduce this in our test environment in isolation from other users/request. But we do use a seperate connection for COPY from the stdin for the initial upload. How can I detect session blockage?

Comment: https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Lock_Monitoring

Comment: Note: There also is a logical problem in your update: `UNIQUE (project_id, email),` only the  email is used as a join-condition.

Answer (score 1):

You should first determine if you are stuck in a lock. Does `pg_locks` contain rows with the long running backend's process ID and `granted = FALSE`?

If that is not the case, find the bottleneck. Does the backend process saturate a CPU? Is your I/O subsystem constantly busy?

You should also use `EXPLAIN` to examine the execution plan. Is there anything suspicious that could explain the duration?

It can be very helpful to test the query on a smaller data set where it finishes. That would enable you to run `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)` which is the best starting point to debug your query. Check first if you have the same execution plan though.

One thing that can slow down data modification considerably are indexes. Have you got a lot of them? Often it is fastest to drop all indexes and constraints before a bulk update and re-create them afterwards.